# linux-shell: renaming files to creation time

Tags: linux, shell, imagemagick

Good morning everybody,

for a website I'd like to rename files(pictures) in a folder from "1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg ..." to "yyyymmdd_hhmmss.jpg" - so I'd like to read out the creation times an set this times as names for the pics. Does anybody have an idea how to do that for example with a linux-shell or with imagemagick?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean the Unix time at which the file was created in the directory or the time that the EXIF data in the file says the photo was taken?

Comment: Take a look to [`jhead`](https://www.sentex.ca/~mwandel/jhead/), a nice tool to rename pictures with (or without) EXIF data.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

#### Naming based on file system date

In the linux shell:

```
for f in *.jpg
do
    mv -n "$f" "$(date -r "$f" +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").jpg"
done
```

*Explanation*:

- `for f in *.jpg
  do`

  This starts the loop over all jpeg files.  A feature of this is that it will work with all file names, even ones with spaces, tabs or other difficult characters in the names.
- `mv -n "$f" "$(date -r "$f" +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").jpg"`

  This renames the file.  It uses the `-r` option which tells `date` to display the date of the file rather than the current date.  The specification `+"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"` tells `date` to format it as you specified.

  The file name, `$f`, is placed in double quotes where ever it is used.  This assures that odd file names will not cause errors.

  The `-n` option to `mv` tells move never to overwrite an existing file.
- `done`

  This completes the loop.

For interactive use, you may prefer that the command is all on one line.  In that case, use:

```
for f in *.jpg; do mv -n "$f" "$(date -r "$f" +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").jpg"; done
```

#### Naming based on EXIF Create Date

To name the file based on the EXIF Create Date (instead of the file system date), we need `exiftool` or equivalent:

```
for f in *.jpg
do
    mv -n "$f" "$(exiftool -d "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S" -CreateDate "$f" | awk '{print $4".jpg"}')"
done
```

*Explanation*:

The above is quite similar to the commands for the file date but with the use of `exiftool` and `awk` to extract the EXIF image Create Date.

- The `exiftool` command provides the date in a format like:

  ```
  $ exiftool -d "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"  -CreateDate sample.jpg
  Create Date                     : 20121027_181338
  ```

  The actual date that we want is the fourth field in the output.
- We pass the `exiftool` output to `awk` so that it can extract the field that we want:

  ```
  awk '{print $4".jpg"}'
  ```

  This selects the date field and also adds on the `.jpg` extension.

Comment: Also `mv -n "$f" "$(stat -c '%W' "$f").jpg"` which renames according to the birth date/creation date of the file. Actually `date -d` gives me the last modified time (but I'm on Cygwin + Windows).

Comment: To complete, to do the same on subfolders: ```find . -type f | grep JPG$ | xargs -I{} sh -c 'mv -n "$1" $(date -r "$1" +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").jpg' - "{}"```

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @John1024 !

I needed to rename files with different extensions in the same time, according to last modification date :

```
for f in *; do
  fn=$(basename "$f")
  mv "$fn" "$(date -r "$f" +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")_$fn"
done
```

"DSC_0189.JPG" ➜ "2016-02-21_18-22-15_DSC_0189.JPG"

"MOV_0131.avi" ➜ "2016-01-01_20-30-31_MOV_0131.avi"

If you don't want to keep original filename :

```
mv "$fn" "$(date -r "$pathAndFileName" +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")"
```

Hope it helps noobs as me !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for file in `ls -1 *.jpg`; do name=`stat -c %y $file | awk -F"." '{ print $1 }' | sed -e "s/\-//g" -e "s/\://g" -e "s/[ ]/_/g"`.jpg; mv $file $name; done
```

Though there might be an easier way.

Comment: Pleasae suggest something

Answer (score 1):

I created a shell script; I think it's mac only, linux might need other arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash

BASEDIR=$1;
for file in `ls -1 $BASEDIR`; do 
    TIMESTAMP=`stat -f "%B" $BASEDIR/$file`;
    DATENAME=`date -r $TIMESTAMP +'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'`-$file
    mv -v $BASEDIR/$file $BASEDIR/$DATENAME;
done
```

when called with a directory path, moves all files in that directory to prepend the creation date of that file, like

```
../camera/P1210232.JPG -> ../camera/20220121-103456-P1210232.JPG
```

Answer (score 0):

Change filename based on file creation time:

```
exiftool "-filename<FileCreateDate" -d %Y%m%d_%H%M%S%z%%-c.%%le input.jpg
```