# How to rename a list of files in directory based on creation time on mac

Tags: bash, shell, date, rename, file-rename

I'm on a **Mac bash console**.

I googled al lot (even here in stack overflow) and tried a lot of scripts in order to **rename each file in a directory with its creation timestamp** via a bash command, but none worked, because `date` and `stat` commands are different in mac rather than in linux. Also I do not have `exif` command.

I'd like to rename with format like this (or anyway similar): *YYYYmmDD-HHMM*

Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot in advance

**EDIT**

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152995/linux-shell-renaming-files-to-creation-time), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43338/renaming-a-bunch-of-files-with-date-modified-timestamp-at-the-end-of-the-filenam) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/749204/how-to-rename-the-file-name-with-timestamp-of-created-date-by-javascript-perl-o)

**EDIT 2**

I'd like to rename with format like this (or anyway similar): *YYYYmmDD-HHMM.jpg* (jpg is an example of file extension, I'd like to not to lose file extension)

**EDIT 3**

Currently this command partially works (always apply jpg extension)

```
for f in `ls`; do mv "$f" "$(stat -t %Y%m%d-%H%M $f | awk -F"\"" '{print $8}').jpg"; done
```

Comment: Do you have the default Mac OS X utils or installed GNU coreutils?

Comment: @Inian, how can I check?

Comment: type `stat --version` and paste the output seen.

Comment: here the output: `$ which stat` -> `/usr/bin/stat`

Comment: run the --version command

Comment: Apple's [`stat`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) seems to support an option `-t timefmt` similar to [`strftime`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strftime.3.html)...

Comment: illegal option "--version", sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mv fileName `stat -f %SB -t %Y%m%d-%H%M fileName`
```

**EDIT**

here final solution, looping among whole file list

```
for f in `ls`;
    do mv "$f" "`stat -f %SB -t %Y%m%d-%H%M $f`.`echo $f | cut -d '.' -f 2`";
done
```

Comment: file extension gets lost, how can I prevent it?

Comment: assume your file name is in this format `name.extension`, you can try `echo fileName | cut -d '.' -f 2`

Comment: `for f in $(ls)` is inherently buggy -- see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Much better to make it `for f in *; do`. There are also some missing quotes that will make this code fail if run with filenames containing spaces; consider running it through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what that identifies.

Answer (score 0):

To prefix/prepend every file in a folder with the **creation date** in the format `%Y%m%d-%H%M` (e.g. `20200722-1352`), run the following snippet:

```
for filename in *; do
  mv "$filename" "$(stat -f "%SB %N" -t "%Y%m%d-%H%M" "$filename")"
done
```

#### Customizing the format / understanding what this command does:

The `-f` parameter will in this case serve as the format of the output filename, where `%SB %N` means:

- use `S`tring output
- print `B`irth date (creation time)
- print a space
- print the original file`N`ame.

The `-t` parameter expands on the date format itself. Feel free to modify those to suit your needs. See FORMATS section in the [manual for `stat`](https://ss64.com/osx/stat.html) on all the possibilities.

If you wish to drop the original filename and only keep the date and the extension, we can adjust the format parameter not to include the filename, and manually append the extracted extension `${filename##*.}`:

```
for filename in *; do
  mv "$filename" "$(stat -f "%SB" -t "%Y%m%d-%H%M" "${filename}").${filename##*.}"
done
```