# Renaming files (photos) in Linux shell based on date (modified or created)

Tags: linux, shell, batch-rename

I'm renaming a lot of photos on Linux. The photos are backups/extracted from an Iphone, and I've decided to do so based on the following format:

`YYYY-mm-dd-ios_photo-HH_ss_mm.ext`

Where the date and time is equal to the creation date (or modified date, as my file system seems to tag them with).

I've been able to rename a bunch with the following `exiftool` command:

```
exiftool -d %Y-%m-%d-ios_photo-%H_%M_%S%%c.%%e "-FileName<CreateDate" *
```

where %%c increment on files that lands on a duplicate time of creation/modified down to the second (%s).

Examples of file names would then be:

```
2020-12-06-ios_photo-09_56_13.JPG
2020-12-06-ios_photo-09_56_131.JPG (for the second picture at the s = 13 timestamp)
2020-12-06-ios_photo-09_56_132.JPG (for the third picture at the s = 13 timestamp)
```

To rename those who, for some reason, won't be renamed using exiftools, I've found the following command in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152995/linux-shell-renaming-files-to-creation-time) stack-post:

```
for f in *.jpg
do
    mv -n "$f" "$(date -r "$f" +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").jpg"
done
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
for f in *.jpg; do mv -n "$f" "$(date -r "$f" +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").jpg"; done
```

The command works, and is able to rename the files to the format I want. However, it does *not* seem to do the increment-thing (`%%c`), which might result in overwrites.

**The question** is as follows:

I'm doing a batch rename of photos. How can I make the latter command increment duplicate files like in the example above, such as to avoid overwrites? Or is there some other command I could use, equal to `%%c` in exif?

Or is there any better tools that would achieve the same result?

The files that exif wasn't able to extract tag information from was both JPG and PNG, and I'm quite sure that all of them are photos that have been received and saved via chat services (e.g. Wire), or screenshots.

I'm not a proper Linux wizard, only a wizzard of sorts, so as you might suspect I'm not at a point where I can cook up my own bash scripts to do this

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Ah, yeah, I can try there too. I just posted it here on Stack Overflow since the post I linked (and from which I'm basing part of the question) was posted here :)